# how may threads might I expect from eclipse?

Tags: eclipse

I have a similar issue to what is described here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6754628/eclipse-crashes-with-unable-to-create-new-native-thread-any-ideas-my-setti

I looked at the taskmenager and saw that the eclipse proccess had over 800 threads running...
Is this reasonable? or is this a result of some other original problem?

My eclipse is:
Version: Helios Service Release 1
Build id: 20100917-0705
and has the following settings in its eclipse.ini:

```
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.1.0.v20100507.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_1.1.1.R36x_v20100810
-product
org.eclipse.epp.package.php.product
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
384M
-showsplash
org.eclipse.platform
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
384m
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
-vm
C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre6\bin\javaw.exe
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.5
-Xms40m
-Xmx384m
-Xss1024k
```

Answer (score 0):

I usually observe 20 to 30 jvm threads, and wouldn't expect the number of native ones to be much larger. So, this looks like a bug.